# Ввожу точность,и программа останавливается

Tags: python, python-3.x

Типичная математическая лабораторная для начального курса
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код написал,отладку завершил но возникла проблема при работе с программой.

После ввода с клавиатуры точность e, программа просто останавливается,как видно на скриншоте.
Я подумал,что может долго считает(а вдруг?),но ничего так и не произошло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам код программы вот:

```
numb1=1.0;
kk=1;
sum=0.0;
print("Введите точность e")
ee=float(input())
while math.fabs(numb1)>ee:
      sum+=numb1
      numb1=1/(math.pow(kk+1,2))
print("Сумма чисел ряда равна = ", sum)
```

Точность у меня `ee` и ввожу я её через `float(input())`,далее цикл с условием "пока элемент ряда больше точности" выполнять.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы не увеличиваете значение `kk`

```
numb1=1.0;
kk=1;
sum=0.0;
print("Введите точность e")
ee=float(input())
while math.fabs(numb1)>ee:
      sum+=numb1
      numb1=1/(math.pow(kk+1,2))
      kk += 1
print("Сумма чисел ряда равна = ", sum)
```

я переписал бы ваш код так:

```
k = 1
sum_ = 0
e = float(input("Введите точность e: "))

while True:
    n = 1 / (k * k)
    sum_ += n
    k += 1
    if abs(n) < e:
         break

print("Сумма чисел ряда равна = ", sum_)
```

при желании можете увеличить точность с помощью `Decimal`

```
import decimal

k = decimal.Decimal(1)
sum_ = 0
e = float(input("Введите точность e: "))

while True:
    n = 1 / (k * k)
    sum_ += n
    k += 1
    if abs(n) < e:
         break
    
print("Сумма чисел ряда равна = ", sum_)
```

Answer (score 4):

Самая часто используемая функция любого программиста - `print()`.  Она позволяет видеть значение неполных переменных. И если добавить в цикл `print(numb1)`, то станет видно, что `numb1` совсем не изменяется и всегда равно 0.25. После этого уже можно искать причину. А причина в том,  что не изменяется значение kk, на основе которого вычисляется numb1 (
`1/(math.pow(kk+1,2)`), где kk всегда 1, т.е. numb1 всегда равно 1/4).

Короче,  добавь в цикл `kk = kk + 1` и в не стесняйся использовать   `print()`, если что-то идёт не так.

Comment: а за что ваз забанили?

Comment: @Danis за то, что называл лентяев лентяями.

Comment: @Эникейщик это оценочное суждение, люди сами вправе решать, как и что жить, это не форум по наставлению в жизни, поэтому если не хотите отвечать, то лучше не отвечать

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов и почему же вы тогда сейчас даете мне наставления? И оценочные суждения тут высказывать не запрещено.